# create new variable in sql

Tags: sql

I have data with net salary. I have to create new variable in my table with name revised salary such that `salary>150000` will be divided by 12 and rest of salary will be as it is. What is sql code?

Comment: Use a `case` expression.

Comment: SQL has no variables. Do you mean "column"?

Comment: Which database are you using? Do you want this to be used in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use update -

```
update tablename 
  set salary = case when salary>150000 then salary/12 else salary end
```

Or if you need only selection then -

```
select *, case when case when salary>150000 then salary/12 else salary end as revised_salary 
from tablename
```

Comment: will it create new variable along with original variable salary

Comment: @spyder, which one? first one will not create new variable it just updates the original one